Why am I not getting approval emails from the "Start and wait for an approval" action
I used to be able to receive approver emails before but it seems it just stopped couple of days ago. I can still get the approvals in MS Teams no issues.
In the screenshot below I have set the settings to Yes.
Anyone going through this issue and what's the resolution?
Is this a Microsoft issue?


Contact MS Support - it might be an internal issue. Similar case in other posts, no one definitive way to solve it - it just should work out of box.

Thanks Kristaps Vilerts, The interesting thin though is if I send it to another user. They get the email. Why am i not getting it. FYI my account is the one runnint the flow and also i'm assigning to the same account. Could this be the reason?

For me it works perfectly, just have à look in your Teams notifications panel

